# iPhone picking/unproject when in landscape view (projection matrix is rotated)

Tags: iphone, math, opengl-es, matrix, glu

I am trying to get 'picking' working in a 3D scene, where the view is rotated such that the iPhone is being held in a landscape mode. I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 (so all shaders, no fixed-function pipeline).

I'm performing the unproject from within the rendering code and immediately drawing the resulting ray using GL_LINES (ray only gets calculated the 1st time that I touch the screen, so afterwards I can move the camera around to observe the resulting line from various angles).

My unproject code/call is fine (lots of examples of gluUnproject online). My matrix-inversion code is fine (even compared with excel for a few matrices). However, the resulting ray is off by at least 5-15 degrees from where I actually 'clicked' (in the Simulator it really is a click, so I'm expecting a lot more precision from the unproject).

My view is rotated to landscape (after I create the perspective-projection matrix, I rotate it around the Z by -90 degrees; the aspect ratio remains at a portrait one). I believe that the problem with the math being off lies here.

Does anyone have any experience doing picking/unprojection with specifically a landscape view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you simply have the field of view off? Assuming you've stuck to something a lot like the traditional pipeline, if you were inverting your modelview matrix then using generic unproject code (ie, code that assumes a 90 degree field of view in both directions to fill eye space) then that would explain it.

A quick diagnostic test is to see how far off it is for different touches. Touches nearer the centre of projection should be closer to the correct answer.

On a screen with square pixels like the iPhone, the aspect ratio is just the proportion of the horizontal field compared to the vertical. So if you want to be unscientific about it, find the field of view you're using, say f, and try multiplying your results by 90/f or f/90. If that doesn't work, try also throwing a factor of 480/320 or 320/480 in there.

A better solution is to follow your code through and figure out what your actual horizontal and vertical fields of view are. And multiply your results by that over 90.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Indeed my FOV is, I think, 60. I do recall seeing the behavior where touches further away from the center were off more. If I temporarily made my FOV 90-degrees, I should expect to see more accuracy from the unproject then?

Comment: If both your horizontal and vertical fields of view were 90 (leading to the graphics to be short and fat, since your viewport isn't square) then you should get perfect results. If you're specifying a vertical field of view to a gluPerspective-style function in your matrix stuff then that should become the horizontal field of view when rotated.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix the general case by trial-and-error. Sometimes I'd have seemingly perfect accuracy in the center of the screen, but it would get worse again towards the edges. I noticed that the typical frustum-projection matrix calculation has a cotangent in there (applied to the fov & aspect-ratio), so perhaps the 'correction factor' that I need to apply to the result isn't linear.

Comment: Oh, right. Possibly a spherical-Cartesian mix up? The rows (and columns) on the screen don't proceed linearly in angle from the observer. E.g. the column at n units from the centre of projection on the front clip plane, which is at a distance of d from the camera, is at an angle of atan(n/d). Unproject usually gives you a vector pointing to a location on the clip plane (or such other plane parallel to it as you dictate) though, making that not a consideration.

Comment: What seems strange to me is how do any OpenGL programs (e.g. on Windows, where you have a non-1.0 aspect ratio and a non-90-degree FOV) handle this unprojection? It seems like all the iPhone tutorial work fine in portrait mode, but specifically switching to landscape is a challenge.

Comment: I got something passable working. I took the clip coordinates of the screen touch (-1 to 1 on both X and Y) and rotated my camera's forward (or 'eye') direction horizontally (around Y axis) by half of the horizontal FOV times the x clip coord and then vertically (around X axis) by half of the vertical FOV times the y clip coord.